# Ring homomorphisms from $A[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings. In one of my classes, we were studying $\operatorname{Hom}(A[X],B)$ and so the teacher got a ring morphism $f:A[X]\to B$ and stated: Since $f$ is a ring homomorphism,

$$f\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(a_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(a_i)f(x^i)$$

So with the first equal sign everything's okay. Since $f$ separates sum between any given two polynomials. However, I don't see how the product separation of two polynomials, implies $f(a_i x^i)=f(a_i)f(x^i)$, since the $\textit{product}$ of $a_ix^i$ is a formal product. Is the equality above even true?

Comment: A small detail for correctness: your sums should start at $0$, because the constants polynomials $a$ are also in $A[X]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But $a_ix^i$ is not **just** a formal product, it is actually a product
of two polynomials, viz,,
$$a_i= a_i +0x+0x^2+\cdots$$
and
$$x^i=0+0x+\cdots+0x^{i-1}+1x^i+0x^{i+1}+\cdots.$$
So indeed in a ring homomorphism from $A$,
$$f(a_ix^i)=f(a_i)f(x^i).$$

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $A[X]$ are formal sums $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^i$. The *multiplication* on $A[X]$ is defined in such a way that, for instance, the product of (the formal sum) $a$ and (the formal sum) $X$ is (the formal sum) $a X$. So, indeed (the formal sum) $a_i X^i$ is the product of $a_i$ and $i$ copies of $X$ and the homomorphism $f$ passes through this multiplication.